# How to parse JSON placed in resource folder in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

Hi I am trying to parse a JSON that I have saved in a resource folder and test it.
So I took these steps for now.

**DataLoader.java**

```
@Service
public class DataLoader {

private static ObjectMapper  objectMapper = defaultObjectMapper();

  private static ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper(){
    ObjectMapper  defaultObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //defaultObjectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    return defaultObjectMapper;
  }

  public static JsonNode parse(String str) throws IOException {
    return objectMapper.readTree(str);
  }

  public static <A> A fromJason(JsonNode node, Class<A> clazz) throws JsonProcessingException {
    return objectMapper.treeToValue(node, clazz);
  }

}
```

**DataLoaderTest.java**

```
public class DataLoaderTest {

    @Value("classpath:data/novo.json")
    Resource jsonSource;

    //private String jsonSource = "{\"title\":\"new book\"}";

    @Test
    public void parse() throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = DataLoader.parse(jsonSource);
        assertEquals(node.get("title").asText(), "new book");
    }

    @Test
    public void fromJson() throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = DataLoader.parse(jsonSource);
        Fruit pojo = DataLoader.fromJason(node, Fruit.class);
        System.out.println("Pojo title " + pojo.title);
    }

}
```

So when I test it with  `//private String jsonSource = "{\"title\":\"new book\"}";`
everything is working fine.

When I try to load JSON file from resources folder I am getting error:

`error: incompatible types: Resource cannot be converted`
`to String JsonNode node = ApxDataLoader.parse(jsonSource);`

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

with Spring-boot, the easy way to load a json in the classpath (for example in the `resources` folder) would be :

```
File jsonFile = new ClassPathResource("data.json").getFile();
// or
File jsonFile = jsonResource.getFile();

JsonNode node = objectMapper.readTree(jsonFile);
```

No need to deal with InputStream, Spring takes care of that for you.  and Jackson can read a `File` directly, so no need for a `String` neither.

No need to deal with `JsonNode` neither: You can also even further optimize the readability of the code by doing all the parsing/mapping at the same time :

```
Fruit myFruit = objectMapper.readValue(jsonFile, Fruit.class);
```

If you still need the contents of the file as a String for some reason:

```
String jsonString = Files.readString(jsonFile.toPath()); // default charset of readString is UTF8
```

`DataLoader` could have only one method:

```
public class DataLoader {

  // ... objectmapper stuff ...

  public static <A> A fromJason(Resource jsonResource, Class<A> clazz) throws JsonProcessingException {
    return objectMapper.readValue(jsonResource.getFile(), clazz);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Resource` object is not a string.
To parse it to the appropriate JSON structure, you would have to read the `Resource`.
See: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-load-resource-as-string

Here's: The relevant part copied from the article.

```
public static String asString(Resource resource) {
        try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream(), UTF_8)) {
            return FileCopyUtils.copyToString(reader);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }
```

Which should give you the string read from the `Resource`.

Another option you have is to use the `InputStream` from the resource and pass it to the overloaded `readTree()` method that can take an input stream.

See : https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree(java.io.InputStream)

I would recommend the second approach instead of reading the whole file as a String and then passing it to the ObjectMapper.

Comment: Ok, yes. Thank you for your answer.  Where do I put this class? If you take a look at my `parse function` in  `DataLoader` class you will see that I am sending `String`. Is something that I have to change there maybe?

Comment: You can change the method `Dataloader::parse(Str)` to `Dataloader::parse(InputStream)` and pass `Resource.getInputStream()` to it.